# How can I extract html escape chars/entities as text when scraping web? (ruby & nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, html-entities

In my ruby+mechanize(nokogiri) script I use this piece of code:

```
row.at_xpath('td[3]/div[1]/a/text()').to_s.strip
```

on a forum where the post title html looks like:

```
<a href="showthread.php?t=233891" >&lt;/body&gt; on Footer ?</a>
```

and I receive from xpath this string **`&lt;/body&gt; on Footer ?`**

I would like to get what I can see in the web browser **`</body> on Footer ?`**

How can I do that for all html escape characters/entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-to-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby), to unescape htmlentities

or

There is a ruby package called [htmlentities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: @S.Mark: I didn't know it was called entities (too). htmlentities works like a charm.Thank you.

Comment: i think its easier to with nokogiri itself a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567029/how-to-make-nokogiri-transparently-return-un-encoded-html-entities-untouched