# Scraping with Nokogiri::HTML - Can't get text from XPATH

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape html with Nokogiri.
This is the html source:

```
<span id="J_WlAreaInfo" class="wl-areacon">
    <span id="J-From">山东济南</span>
    至
    <span id="J-To">
        <span id="J_WlAddressInfo" class="wl-addressinfo" title="全国">
            全国
            <s></s>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I need to get the following text: 山东济南

Checked shortest XPATH with firebug:

```
//*[@id="J-From"]
```

Here is my ruby code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://foo.html"), "UTF-8")
area = doc.xpath('//*[@id="J-From"]')
puts area.text
```

However, it returns nothing. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can give us a link to the page? Also, can you look at the page source as originally served: possibly it's creating the `<span id="J-From">` in javascript after the page loads, but Nokogiri isn't seeing such things?

Comment: you may want to look at the top voted answer here regarding open uri http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572396/nokogiri-open-uri-and-unicode-characters

Comment: Thank you guys a thousand times, it is a JS problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

xpath() returns an array containing the matches (it's actually called a NodeSet):

```
require 'nokogiri'


html = %q{
<span id="J_WlAreaInfo" class="wl-areacon">
    <span id="J-From">山东济南</span>
    至
    <span id="J-To">
        <span id="J_WlAddressInfo" class="wl-addressinfo" title="全国">
            全国
            <s></s>
        </span>
    </span>
</span> 
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
target_tags = doc.xpath('//*[@id="J-From"]')

target_tags.each do |target_tag|
  puts target_tag.text
end

--output:--
山东济南
```

**Edit: You can actually call `text()` on the Array, but it will return the concatenated results of the text for each match in the array--which is not something I've ever found useful--but because there is only one match you *should* have gotten the result `山东济南`. There is nothing in your post that indicates why you didn't get that result.**

If you only want a single result from your xpath, i.e. the first match, then you can use `at_xpath()`:

```
target_tag = doc.at_xpath('//*[@id="J-From"]')
puts target_tag.text

--output:--
山东济南
```

Comment: i can reproduce the same issue as the OP. I'm also getting a blank string so it may be a local machine issue.  what's weird is that nokogiri can get the node but the text is a blank string.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, the issue was with JavaScript. Nokogiri returned nothing because there was nothing there.