# How to prevent Nokogiri from encoding entities in HTML fragments

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, html-entities

Nokogiri 1.5.0

I'm unable to output a parsed fragment with a link having query parameters, specifically with the ampersand in the href. The ampersand is replaced by its html entity.

```
f = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(%q{<a href="http://example.com?this=1&that=2">Testing</a>})
f.to_s    # => "<a href=\"http://example.com?this=1&amp;that=2\">Testing</a>"
f.to_html # => "<a href=\"http://example.com?this=1&amp;that=2\">Testing</a>"
```

No help using `to_html(encoding: 'UTF-8')` or US-ASCII.

This would seem pretty common, parsing a valid link format and wanting to render that back as valid HTML.

[How to make Nokogiri transparently return un/encoded Html entities untouched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567029/how-to-make-nokogiri-transparently-return-un-encoded-html-entities-untouched) was no help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nokogiri's HTML parser automatically corrects errors in the source document. The naked ampersand in the URL is [actually an error](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp), so Nokogiri is correcting it. If you look at `f.errors`, you can see that it doesn't think that `&that` is a valid entity and is missing a semicolon, so it fixes the ampersand to `&amp;`, making it valid HTML.

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference.