# Encoding html in rails

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently working with many XML files and some of the data is encoded as below. How do I work with this data? Up until now I have been just simply using gsub() to replace the characters for blanks! Maybe there is an easier way.

```
Here is the description &amp;lt;br&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br
&amp;gt;Here is some more text
```

I have been doing this:

```
gsub('&amp;','')
```

Or this:

```
gsub('&amp;','&')
```

Comment: Your data is double-encoded. `<` has become `&lt;` which has been re-encoded to become `&amp;lt;`. How did your files become encoded in the first place? Are they stored in a database?

Comment: They are 3rd party data feeds, unfortunately I have no control over it :(

Comment: You need to [decode them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-to-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby/1600584#1600584), twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use CGI.unescapeHTML to decode the data http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000096.
I hope this would help.