# How to decode HTML entities in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html-entities, html-encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I encode/decode HTML entities in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby)

I would like to convert strings like this:

```
"I&#39;m working"
```

to

```
"I'm working"
```

(i.e. decode HTML entities)

What Ruby/Rails function does the trick ?

I want to use this function in the model.