# how can I reverse an html decimal special characters back to normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Specifically, suppose I start with the string

```
  string ="hello \'i am \' me"
```

And then I textilize the string to get an output:

```
  textilize(string) => "<p>hello &#8217;i am &#8217; me</p>"
```

And then, because I want to get a count of the characters visible to a person, I wish to strip the html tags, and reverse the special characters ’ to the simple apostrophe they are (ie ' or \'). Strip_tags is easy enough:

```
 strip_tags(textilize(string)) => "hello &#8217;i am &#8217; me"
```

But I don't know how to reverse the special characters. If it helps, I know the method html_escape would have turned some characters like angle brackets into the decimal form:

```
 html_escape(">") => "&gt;"
```

But I don't know of a rails method to reverse this. Anyone have suggestions on either a custom method or a rails method to accomplish this task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I encode/decode HTML entities in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's something built into Rails for this, but there is a [library](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) that can do it. It may even come with Rails since I have it but did not install it separately:

```
require 'htmlentities'

HTMLEntities.new.decode("&gt;") # =>  ">"
HTMLEntities.new.encode(">") # => "&gt;"
```

Comment: Hey Beerlington. Thanks for the answer. I think I will check if the other one works first, just to avoid installing a gem over this. BUT his isn't working yet, so yours may be the answer! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CGI::unescapeHTML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescapeHTML)

```
> CGI::unescapeHTML("Usage: foo &quot;bar&quot; &lt;baz&gt;")
=> "Usage: foo \"bar\" <baz>"
```

*Edit: +1 @Beerlington for `htmlentities`.  I always forget it exists.