# Parsing HTML with a weird encoding with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I can't use XPath because the encoding gets weird. I hoped you could help me out of this trouble.

```
require "Nokogiri"
require "open-uri"
link = "http://www.arla.dk/Services/SearchService.asmx/RecipeResult?q=allRecipe&paging=6&include=&exclude=&area=recipeSearch&languageBranch=da"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
doc.xpath("//h2")
```

The `xpath` method returns an empty array. It looks like the document has not been parsed correct. I think it is due to the file being parsed contains the encoded characters:

```
&lt;strong&gt;Frokost til 8&lt;/strong&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li class='ingHeading'&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;b&gt;Flade
```

Comment: This is not a nokogiri problem, it's a problem with the source data, which is encoded as one long string.

Comment: Interesting, I will see if I can find some tool for converting it. Do you know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is XML so first parse it with Nokogiri::XML:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML open(link)
```

then the first string contains some HTML so parse that with Nokogiri::HTML

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML xml.at('string').text
```

Now you can do your search:

```
doc.xpath '//h2'
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the issue is that the HTML is encoded, which is why you are seeing escape sequences; For example, `&lt;` instead of `<`. To get around it, unescape the HTML.

"[How do I encode/decode HTML entities in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby) basically suggests using [htmlentities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/).