# How to convert HTML/asp code into ruby string

Tags: asp.net, html, ruby

Is there any way to easily convert HTML/asp code into a format so that it can be used as a string?

So, like there is some HTML/asp code, and I want to use this as string in ruby code. Is there any way to convert the HTML code into ruby string format?

Or is there anyway I can make the string of the ruby code to reference some HTML/asp file?

Edit: No, what I want to do is, I have some HTML code in HTML file, and I want to use it exactly as a string in ruby code.

For example,

I have code like   blahblah  and asp stuffs

Then I want to use the exact code as similar to this:

var = The code above.

But HTML/ASP code will have special characters that will make it hard to embed as a string. So is there any way to use the whole chunk as a string without encountering problem?

Comment: Maybe I do not fully understand you, but there is nothing special with HTML in string: you can just read it from file and put into string var, whatever.

Comment: Maybe take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby)

Comment: @user201097 It would be a lot easier to answer if you gave an example too.

Comment: This question makes no sense as it is. Please edit it to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This retrieves a web page and stores it into a string:

```
require 'open-uri'
html = open('http://www.example.com').read
puts html[0, 60]
```

Which outputs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
```