# Is it possible to escape &amp; &apos; present in database?

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails, xml, html-entities

The data retrieved from database has `&amp;` or `&apos;`. How do I escape and show as `&` or `'` without using gsub method?

Comment: The problem is that character entity references are saved in the database in the first place. The question is tagged both HTML and XML, which is it?

Comment: &apos; is not html entity, it's XML entity am i right?

Comment: [It's both](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't stop the data from being inserted like that, then there is code [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,246527,246527) to create a function in MySQL that you can use in your query in order to return the decoded data.

Or from within Ruby, not using a replace strategy, take a look at [how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby).

Comment: From within the db it would have to be replace. But there are other methods in Ruby. I've updated my answer with link to previous question about doing this in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, an escape-sequence is found in string-analysis only, not in html or XML where you talk of masquerading. You can escape a string for reasons of concatenation for example. Html-Entities are specific entities which are replaced in urns to masquerade a special character. It is absolutely wrong to save strings still containing html-entities in a db-table. The masked string has to be demasked first, after you "reget" it from post :). Otherwise you try to save html-entities in a special table, eg. for programming reasons. A text-file should do better - try dBase 2 - or simply google the web for a page with an entity-listing.

The second point is that XML is - for the realization of better reading of your own code (in general), thought to be a personally defined markup-language. That is why any non-std-tags within that specification, have to be defined by your own. (It was strange to read about regular entities as "XML-entities", like in the case of "&apos(;)", explained on this entity-page: http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/unicode/htmlent.html)
Std-XML-tags (not entities) are mainly important in aspects of finalizing your html-code to better fit to ongoing programming languages later on, but in my opinion the mentioned ones are still html-entities!

Answer (score 0):

This can and should be performed on the view level, ie, the front-end, since its an [HTML entity](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp).

assuming you use jquery, you can do this to make `&apos;` appear as `'` on the HTML.

`$('<div/>').html('&#39;').text()`

You can find respective entity values in the link above