# Get request response is in weird format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I send a get request to a local (separate from app) jetty web server

```
RestClient.get("ip/command/core/get-version", {})
```

Then I do a `JSON.parse()` on the response.

As a result I get

```
{&quot;revision&quot;=&gt;&quot;r2407&quot;, &quot;full_version&quot;=&gt;&quot;2.5 [r2407]&quot;, &quot;full_name&quot;=&gt;&quot; [r2407]&quot;, &quot;version&quot;=&gt;&quot;2.5&quot;}
```

What's wrong? How do I turn it into a hash, so I can extract the full_version property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String returned by service is html encoded. Try decoding it first:

```
JSON.parse(CGI.unescape_html(response_body))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response looks to be encoded into HTML entities.

If you are using Ruby, try [decoding the response using `CGI.unescape_html`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby) prior to running `JSON.parse`. Running the result of that method through `JSON.parse` should give you your hash.