# How to unescape/decode escaped HTML characters?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When I using nokogiri to parser htmls, the Chinese characters are transfer to escaped sequences like

"`&aring;&middot;&#133;&aring;&sup3;&deg;&aring;&raquo;&para;&aelig;&#151;&para;`"

How could I decode the escaped characters like "`&aring;&middot;&#133;&aring;&sup3;&deg;&aring;&raquo;&para;&aelig;&#151;&para;`" back to normal characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your HTML page is encoded as UTF-8 but you are parsing as ISO-8859-1. You need to ensure you specify the correct encoding when parsing. If you are parsing from a string Nokogiri should use the same encoding as the string. If you are parsing from an IO object you can specify the encoding as the third argument to the [`parse` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/Document.html#method-c-parse):

```
Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(io_object, nil, 'UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

What should the normal characters be though? This looks like their string representations.

Otherwise you have CGI.unescapeHTML() and CGI.escapeHTML() available in standard ruby (stdlib).