# Transform and Instance Variable into a JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays

How can i transform this instance variable into JavaScript array of objects

I know there is something that i have to do with

but when i try it. it just completely errors out..

This is what i am getting: (comes out with the Quotes)

```
@updates = [
  "{'24548_0_load_results': ['1630609','2015-04-07 13:51:03 UTC','7 minutes']}", 
  "{'24548_0_load_results': ['1630610','2015-04-07 13:51:03 UTC','7 minutes']}"
]
```

Created the above with this:

```
  @updates = []
  records.each do |r|
    updates << "{ '" + t.search_table_id.to_s + "': " + Search.load_post_result(r, s).to_s + " }"
  end
```

This is how i need it:

```
var obj1 = {
    "loads": [
        {'24547_1428357240_load_results' : ['1630607','2015-04-06 18:35:46 UTC','8 minutes']},
        {'24547_1428357240_load_results' : ['1630606','2015-04-06 18:35:47 UTC','8 minutes']}
    ]
};
```

This is the script that i am tring to run this array of objects thru:

```
$.each(obj1["loads"], function(k, v){
    $.each(v, function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ": " + value);
    })
});
```

edit:
This is what i have now

```
var obj1 = {
    "loads": []
};

for (string in <%= @updates1 %>){
    obj1["loads"].push(JSON.parse(string.replace(/'/g,'\"')));
}

$.each(obj1["loads"], function(k, v){
    $.each(v, function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ": " + value);
    })
});
```

And looks like this in the response:

```
var obj1 = {
    "loads": []
};

for (string in [&quot;{ '24549_1428420484_load_results': ['1630610','2015-04-07 14:44:37 UTC','44 minutes','Springfield, MO','Dallas, TX','04/07','04/07','Full','Flatbed or Van or Reefer','','53','0.00'] }&quot;, &quot;{ '24549_1428420484_load_results': ['1630609','2015-04-07 13:51:03 UTC','about 2 hours','Springfield, MO','Dallas, TX','04/10','04/11','Full','Flatbed or Van or Reefer','','53','0.00'] }&quot;]){
    obj1["loads"].push(JSON.parse(string.replace(/'/g,'\"')));
}

$.each(obj1["loads"], function(k, v){
    $.each(v, function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ": " + value);
    })
})
```

;

Comment: You should consider using the [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem.

Comment: I was going to suggest calling `records.as_json`, but Gon is probably a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in javascript like this:

```
    JSON.parse("YourString".replace(/'/g,'\"'))
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate.

https://jsfiddle.net/ab19ha1o/

You need to replace the single quotes to properly parse JSON, so that's a quick and dirty way to do it :)

Edit:  Here's the SO Thread on JSON Parse:  [jQuery.parseJSON single quote vs double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote)

And you would just need to iterate over each string to get the object.

Edit:  The full transfer would look something like this:

```
    for (string in updates){
      obj1["loads"].push(JSON.parse(string.replace(/'/g,'\"')));
    }
```

Comment: I am still having trouble incorportating this i keep getting the unexpected & error... that is probably because it is converting the double quotes to HTML.

Comment: Oh yeah if it's HTML encoding it you'd have to decode it first as well.

Comment: so would  string = <%= escape_javascript(@updates) %>;  BY the way this is in a js.erb file

Comment: Ah, I'd have to see it in the client on what it outputs, I'm not as familiar with ruby.  Can you link what that is actually outputting to the client if you do that?  It's likely you want to store that in an array and then iterate through each string.

Comment: i added the new info... still getting the & error probably here &quot;

Comment: yeah you need to convert the &quot; to "

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby