# Unable to decode double encoded special characters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting data from an api where special characters are are getting double encoded. By that I mean ’ is encoded as &amp;rsquo;. I know how to decode but I am unable to double decode. I've tried raw and html_safe but neither will decode it past &rsquo;, even if i double up i.e. raw raw or .html_safe.html_safe. How can I completely decode these characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I encode/decode HTML entities in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby)

Comment: @infused I don't think this is a duplicate... OP has a condition of double encoding, it's not straight encode / decode HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This works...

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

my_string = "This is Sam&amp;rsquo;s bicycle"

decoded_string = Nokogiri::HTML(my_string.gsub('&amp;','&')).text 

puts decoded_string
=> => "This is Sam's bicycle"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used to have the same problem.
my workaround for all HTML problems is as follows:

```
def format_html_sentence(sentence)
    Nokogiri::HTML.parse(sentence.gsub(/(\\r|\\n)/, '')).text
end
```