# Ruby how to convert special html entities to html code or hex code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I received some html string contains special entities, like `☐`
https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/ballot-box/

I want to convert `☐` to `&#9744;` or HEX CODE `&#x2610;`

So, do a similar job like https://mothereff.in/html-entities

Comment: This is allready answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600584/1900722

Comment: @anquegi yes, I saw it before I posted.Frame number: 0/16
[1] pry(main)> require 'cgi'
=> false
[2] pry(main)> CGI.escapeHTML('☐')
=> "☐"
[3] pry(main)> CGI.unescapeHTML('☐')
=> "☐"