# Encode HTML Script in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to encode HTML Scripts.

I have text like this:

```
"&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w, &lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"
```

I want to only decode

```
&lt; and &gt; to < and >.
```

I have a method like this:

```
def name
  a = [last_name.to_s + ',', first_name].compact.join(' ')
  Loofah.fragment(a).text(encode_special_chars: false) 
end
```

But using Loofah.fragment it is decoding all html scripts ad showing like this:

```
"<a href=\"https://www.w, <script></script>" but I want only < and >
```

Could someone please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I encode/decode HTML entities in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string replace methods in your case like in the below example:

```rb
"&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w, &lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;".gsub("&lt;","<").gsub("&gt;",">")
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600526/how-do-i-encode-decode-html-entities-in-ruby), you can use CGI or Nokogiri:

```rb
CGI.unescapeHTML("&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w, &lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;")

Nokogiri::HTML.parse(""&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w, &lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;")
```

But, as mentioned there as well, you are probably not dealing with raw html in the view helpers right.

```rb
<%= raw '<html>' %>
```